# random key generator with validity check

Tags: php

What if i want to add an option to my website like API !

when anyone call `my.site.dot.com/api.php?id=name` it will add the `name` to my database

but i'm getting a lot of spam entries so i've been thinking about using a key !

so it would be like `my.site.dot.com/api.php?id=name&key=MMSDJJSHHHAG`
if the key is right then it `echo "passed";` and if wrong then `echo "stopped";`

**Now my question**
I want any function that can generate random key either of letters or numbers or both whatever.

but the bottom line is it must be also able to know its keys WHY ! cause when someone call `my.site.dot.com/api.php?id=name&key=MMSDJJSHHHAG` it become able  to know that `MMSDJJSHHHAG` is valid key.

`my.site.dot.com/api.php?id=name&key=MMSDJJSHHHAG`

```
<?PHP
echo $id; //name
echo $key; //MMSDJJSHHHAG

if ( key is valid ) {
echo "passed";
} else {
echo "stopped";
}
?>
```

I know there some other ideas like every time i generate new key to store it in text file or in database table...etc and that are good ideas but i'll generate it upon viewing an page so someone can makes billions of refresh making site down :(

I'm thinking of math equations !! any help about this idea ~ thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hasing/encrypting methods to generate this key you're talking about.
(md5 for instance).

Notice that in order to use API in most webservices you need to have an account,
those services matches a key to an account.

So basicly you have a key for each account (not for each action or refresh),
add another field to your api members' table named "api_key" and you are ready to go.

Relating to your problem , you can also add another field , for instance "site_url",
your api.php file will check the "source" of the `request`.
If the KEY and the SOURCE of the request exists for one account it will do what it need to do , otherwise `die()` or something like this.

Comment: thanks , yes i know it would be better if user gets the key after register and it one key per member , but my idea was based on free api without registration and with random key every time the page viewed anyway thanks a lot and if i didn't found any way to do it , i might back to key upon registration.

Answer (score 1):

If the keys aren't unique to users, then generating a key by any pattern is simply security through obscurity. If someone is already spamming your API, logic would dictate that they have observed the URLs that your application uses and they are already calling them blindly (or intentionally). If you attach a non-unique pattern-generated key, then the observer will simply snoop that URL and spam it as well, unless the key is passed server side in which case any key will do.

Bottom line is you want to stop spam you need to use a real authentication method.